# Bootstrap popover with input-addon styling issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a form that is using bootstrap for styling and the 'popover' that is built in.

My problem is when i have 2 input-group-addons and attach a popover to the first one the item is visually moved over leaving a gap between it and the next addon.

HTML:

```
<div class="amountSelection pull-right form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6">
  <div class="input-group merged" id="faceValueInputDiv">
    <input class="form-control input-lg" value="20"></input>
    <span id="input-addon-pop" class="input-group-addon" 
          data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top"
          data-content="do stuff!" data-trigger="click">
      <i class="fa fa-question-circle">?</i>
    </span>
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-usd">$</i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#input-addon-pop").popover({
  trigger: 'click'
});
```

CSS:

```
.merged input:first-child {
  border-right: 0px;
}

.merged input + .input-group-addon {
  border-left: 0px;
  border-right: 0px;
  background-color: @input-bg;
}
```

Example of it (not) working:
http://www.bootply.com/129977

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research into bootstrap addons with some knowledge i've gained from the past i looked into 'container' option of the popover.

Pushing the popover onto the `<i>` tag I was able to alleviate the whitespace problem

`$("#input-addon-pop").popover({
    trigger: 'click',
    container: '.fa.fa-question-circle'
});`

http://www.bootply.com/129986